# How to set OnClickListener for ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-scrollview

i'm developing an android project which it has a viewpager. i wrote an adapter for my viewpager and my adapter consist of s scrollview and some views inside that.

i want when user click on the scrollview, something happen (i wrote this part too and test it and it works).

i implement onClickListener for my scrollview but it's not triggered when user click on that.

i have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776687/onclicklistener-on-scrollview) but it's not work for me.

my code for onClickListener is here

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.level_selector_list_view_adapter, container, false);
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.level_selector_view_scroll_view);

scroll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Log.e(MainActivity.WATERMELON_TAG, "Click!!!");
        }
});
```

and my layout code is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/level_selector_values_main_page_view_pager_width"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/level_selector_view_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/level_selector_view_pager_adapter_level_logo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_logo_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_logo_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_logo_top_margin"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/level_selector_view_pager_adapter_level_name"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_name_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_name_top_margin"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/level_selector_values_level_name_font_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/level_selector_values_level_name_font_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/level_selector_view_pager_adapter_level_score"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_score_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/level_selector_values_view_pager_adapter_level_score_top_margin"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/level_selector_values_level_name_font_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/level_selector_values_font_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level_selector_view_pager_adapter_lock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/lock"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The child `Views` of your `ScrollView` are consuming the click events you do on the `ScrollView`.

The solution to this problem is to set the `onClickLIstener` to the **immediate** child of the `ScrollView`, the `FrameLayout` in your case.

Don't forget to set the layout to "clickable".

Furthermore, I recommend not to use the `FrameLayout` at all, since it is just a useless container. Instead, just let the `LinearLayout` that is currently the child of the `FrameLayout` be the next child to the `ScrollView`.

Comment: i try this and it doesn't work again! i set clickable all child of scrollview false and also the parent of scrollview. but the result was as same as before :(

Comment: Allright, please edit your question and post your full code and layout.

Comment: as you said, i edit my code and post all you want. thanks a lot for your time and your help :))

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public class ClassName implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        ScrollView scrollView= (ScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.my_ScrollView);

        scrollView.setOnClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.WATERMELON_TAG, "Click!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a good idea at the first look! but i try it doesn't either :((

Comment: Okey, please post your java code as well, and lets see if we can figure it out. I recently made an app which does what you want. The only difference is that i have an textview inside the scrollview which stretches the whole page. Than i made the textView clickable. Oh, and you changed the root.findViewById(R.id.my_scrollView) to R.id.level_selector_view_scroll_view   . Right?

Comment: Philipp Jahoda is correct. Your ScrollView is hidden behind your other Views, therefore you cannot click it. If you would try to make the picture id = level_selector_view_pager_adapter_level_logo  clickable, this would work. Because it is on top of all the views, likewise your TextViews.