# How to handle click on ScrollView in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How to handle click on ScrollView in Fragment?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ExampleFragment">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myScroll">
        </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And in Fragment I'm trying:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ScrollView refresh = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}
```

But after clicking nothing happens.

Any other idea to handle a click on a fragment? This does not have to be a ScrollView. I tried also for FragmentLayout but it returns a lot of bugs.

Comment: did you make debugging? does onclick function run properly? Does the toast show runs properly but does not occur on your screen? Where does the error occurs exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the onClickListener of ScrollView being ignored is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776687/onclicklistener-on-scrollview).

You could add an onTouchListener instead like this.

```
    refresh.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        /**
         * Called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. This allows listeners to
         * get a chance to respond before the target view.
         *
         * @param v     The view the touch event has been dispatched to.
         * @param event The MotionEvent object containing full information about
         *              the event.
         * @return True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           toast.show();             
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this code in onCreateView**

```
 ScrollView refresh = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```