# Android click views within a ScrollView

Tags: android, click, touch, scrollview

I have a layout with 5 items in a LinearLayout in a ScrollView. I want the items to be clickable and not interfere with scrolling.

The problem is scrolling. If drag up/down on an item, it doesn't scroll. If I drag up/down on the margins between the items, it does scroll.

How can I handle click events for items AND allow scrolling when the user drags up/down on an item?

Note: this isn't about efficient layouts or just using a RecyclerView (which seems like overkill). I want to know how to scroll and handle children being clicked.

I've tried various combinations of click and touch listeners, GestureDetector, onInterceptTouchEvent... but I only seem to be able to either click or scroll, not both.

I followed these tutorials/answers and none have worked:

- [Android tutorial on intercepting touch events](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup)
- [How to vary between child and parent view group touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966412/how-to-vary-between-child-and-parent-view-group-touch-events/30966413#30966413)
- [OnClickListener on scrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776687/onclicklistener-on-scrollview)

There must be something simple I'm missing... some flag or something?

**Layout:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itemOne"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:margin="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itemTwo"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:margin="16dp" />

            ...
```

**Activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   itemOne.setOnClickListener(this)
   itemTwo.setOnClickListener(this)
   ...
}

override fun onClick(view: View?) {
   when (view?.id) {
      R.id.itemOne-> ...
      R.id.itemTwo -> ...
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just remove scrollView id in XML to make it unlisted in R file this will make it unclick-able in Listeners

Comment: This did not solve the problem. The problem isn't the scrollview being clickable, it's that the clickable items consume the scroll touch events.